# Dioperads vs polycategories

Tags: ct.category-theory, operads, linear-logic

As defined by [Gan](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0201074), a *dioperad* consists of sets of operations $P(n,m)$ with "$n$ inputs and $m$ outputs", which can be composed by joining *one* output of one operation to *one* input of another, giving rise to composition operations

$$ P(n_1,m_1) \times P(n_2,m_2) \to P(n_1+n_2-1,m_1+m_2-1). $$

Dioperads are apparently motivated by the fact that some [PROPs](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/PROP) are freely generated by dioperads, because they have a generators-and-relations description in which all the relations only involve composites of the sort that exist in a dioperad.  In such a case, the dioperad is evidently a simpler object to study than the entire PROP.

As defined by [Szabo](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927877508822067), a [polycategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/polycategory) has a set of objects, and for any $n$-tuple and $m$-tuple of objects $a_1,\dots,a_n$ and $b_1,\dots,b_m$, a set of morphisms $P(a_1,\dots,a_n; b_1,\dots,b_n)$, with composition operations that join one of the targets of one morphism to one of the sources of another.  If we write $\Gamma,a,\Delta$ for a list of objects containing $a$ somewhere in the middle, then this composition operation looks like

$$P(\Gamma; \Delta,a,\Psi) \times P(\Xi,a,\Upsilon; \Phi) \to P(\Xi,\Gamma,\Upsilon; \Delta,\Phi,\Psi).$$

Polycategories are motivated by providing a semantics for classical [linear logic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/linear+logic), whose cut rule looks like this composition rule:

$$ \frac{\Gamma \vdash \Delta,A,\Psi \qquad \Xi,A,\Upsilon \vdash \Phi}{\Xi,\Gamma,\Upsilon \vdash \Delta,\Phi,\Psi} $$

One generally thinks of the source objects as joined by a "multiplicative conjunction" tensor product $\otimes$ and the target objects as joined instead by a "multiplicative disjunction" tensor product $⅋$, and this can be made precise by showing that "representable" polycategories are precisely [linearly distributive categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/linearly+distributive+category).

It *looks* to me as though (ignoring questions of enrichment) a dioperad is just a one-object polycategory, in the same way that an ordinary operad is a one-object multicategory — or in other words, a polycategory is a "colored dioperad".  Is this true?  If so, is it in print anywhere?  If not, what is the difference?

Comment: Sure looks that way to me, although I've never heard the word "polycategory" before. If memory serves, Gan's definition explicitly requests that the set $P(n,m)$ be a bimodule for the symmetric groups $S_n$ and $S_m$. Certainly I make that request in my couple papers, and Bruno does as well. I assume Szabo also asks for the ability to permute the inputs and outputs? Of course, there really should be both planar (associative) and symmetric (commutative) versions, and probably also $E_d$ versions for all dimensions $d$...

Comment: I'd be willing to put forward the wager that the sentence "Polycategories are colored dioperads" isn't written in the literature. My reason for believing this is that I, as I already said, never heard of polycategories, so I wonder how much literature there is on them (perhaps a lot in linear logic?), and I also don't know of a lot of work on dioperads (Gan's original paper, Bruno's thesis, my couple papers, surely others... but not a lot). Indeed, Bruno showed that the homotopy theories of dioperads and props are really different, and props are usually (but not always) the "correct" choice.

Comment: I would of course be happy to be corrected --- literature I am unaware of is literature I can learn from.

Comment: Polycategories of course also have a symmetric and non-symmetric version, just like all kinds of multicategory/operad.  Szabo's original definition may have been the non-symmetric one, but if that's the only difference then I would regard the answer as being yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Martin Markl's article "[Operads and PROPs](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601129)," just after Def. 64, the dioperad-polycategory connection is briefly mentioned.  Markl attributed this observation to Leinster.

In my book with Mark W. Johnson "[A Foundation for PROPs, Algebras, and Modules](http://bookstore.ams.org/surv-203/)," in Section 11.5 we wrote down the explicit axioms for a colored dioperad.  The relevant graphs and monads were written down earlier in Part I, as explained further down in Section 11.5.  If you take out the equivariant structure of a C-colored dioperad (Def. 11.18), the remaining structure is a polycategory with object set C.